# jquery mobile ajax css refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Using ajax to render a partial view, then on success need to show new data (which works) but the css is not being applied, ideas?

```
$.ajax({
                     url: baseUrl,
                     type: 'GET',
                     data: { date: date },
                     success: function (response) {
                         $('#schedule').html(response);
                     },
                     complete:function() {  $('#listId').listview('refresh');
                     },

                 });
```

View

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true" id="listId">
                    <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
                        @Model.AppointmentDate
                    </li>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Appointments)
                    {
                        <li data-theme="c">
                            <a href="/Schedule/MobileAppointmentEdit/@item.Id" data-transition="slide">
                                @item.StartTime @item.Name
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    }

                </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refresh ul in ajax success but not ajax complete. It is because jquery mobile applys css when the page init, for the data that retrieve dynamically. You have to trigger an event to refresh the UI.

jQuery Mobile listview ref:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos//1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-methods.html

```
success: function (response) {
   $('#schedule').html(response);
   $("#schedule ul").listview();
},
```